# Custom infowindow exception in CartoDB

Tags: carto, api, visualisation

I'm building a runtime layer and til a couple of days ago my code was working. Since today it started giving me an exception that is causing subsequent code not to work.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: layerView is not defined
```

The problem is caused by this call:

```
cdb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(map, sublayer1, ['cartodb_id','ppe_ma']);
```

I guess something has changed in the api but i dunno how to track this changes as these functions are not yet documented.

Comment: could you share the complete example or a subset of it, with that information is hard to guess the problem

Comment: i see. i'm modifying a gist you created for a problem i had in the beginning https://gist.github.com/javisantana/49d31ea2787a53e7ae2d it has the same exception

Comment: Ok, I found the problem, I introduced a regression some days ago, I'm fixing it right now. Sorry about that